# realloc(): invalid next size - realloc dynamic struct

Tags: c, struct, realloc

I started learning about struct in C. Today I found a problem, that I can't solve. I have this code:

```
typedef struct fraze
{
  char *mostSearch = NULL; // for string from user
  double freq;
} s_FRAZE;

int readFraze( )
{
  int i = 2, k;
  size_t len = 0;
  char c;
  s_FRAZE *s;
  s = (s_FRAZE *)malloc( i * sizeof( int ));
  k = 0;
  while( (c = getchar()) != '\n')
  {
    ungetc( c, stdin );

    if( scanf( "%lf%c", &s[k].freq, &c) != 2 || c != ':' )
    {
      return 1;
    }

    if( k + 1 >= i )
    {
      i *= 2;
      printf("%d\n", i );
      s = (s_FRAZE *)realloc( s, i * sizeof( int ));
    }

    len = getline(&s[k].mostSearch, &len, stdin );
    s[k].mostSearch[len-1] = '\0';
    k++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I want to read while user don't type '\n', but it works 2x and then I get this erorr  realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000001559010 ***
I tryed use valgrind and there are more errors:

> ==7662== Invalid write of size 8
>   ==7662==    at 0x56AEBB4: _IO_vfscanf (vfscanf.c:2328)
>   ==7662==    by 0x56BBD3A: scanf (scanf.c:33)
>   ==7662==    by 0x40089F: readFraze() (main.c:31)
>   ==7662==    by 0x400818: main (main.c:15)
>   ==7662==  Address 0x59fe048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
>   ==7662==    at 0x4C27C0F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
>   ==7662==    by 0x400847: readFraze() (main.c:25)
>   ==7662==    by 0x400818: main (main.c:15)
>   ==7662==
>   ==7662== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>   ==7662==    at 0x56BFCA2: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:63)
>   ==7662==    by 0x40093E: readFraze() (main.c:44)
>   ==7662==    by 0x400818: main (main.c:15)

Can anyone tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: Where do you allocate an object for `mostSearch`? And you code does not even compile. It is no valid C code.

Comment: `malloc( i * sizeof( int ));` --> `malloc( i * sizeof( s_FRAZE ));` assuming you want `i` elements in the array.

Comment: Same thing with `realloc( s, i * sizeof( int ));` --> `realloc( s, i * sizeof( s_FRAZE ));`

Comment: For readability by us humans, use meaningful variable names.  single char variable names give no indication as to their contents nor purpose.

Comment: when calling `malloc()` and family of functions, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )  The posted code not only raises numerous warnings, but also raises some errors.  I.E. the posted code will NEVER run until all the errors are fixed.  The only possibility, that I see, is this is not your real code. Please post the real code

Comment: A typedef struct cannot be initialized within the struct so this line, in the typedef, `char *mostSearch = NULL;` will not compile and causes the compiler to think that the fraze struct has no members.

Comment: @Olaf getline malloc memory for string, if length is 0, I found this on internet.

Comment: @user3629249 I compiled with -Wall -pedantic and 0 errors

Comment: the call to `return 1;` after the call to scanf() will leave the user startled and wondering what is wrong with the program that is suddenly exited.  Suggest properly error checking the call to scanf(), to include a call to `perror()`

Comment: when calling `realloc()`, always save the returned value into a temp variable, then check that the temp variable does not contain NULL.  otherwise, when `realloc()` fails (which it can do), the pointer to the currently allocated memory will be overlayed/lost, resulting in a memory leak and a seg fault event if that pointer is de-referenced

Comment: regarding this line: `if( k + 1 >= i )`  while the C operator precedence will properly handle the expression, just reading it tends to be misleading.  For clarity suggest: `if( (k + 1) >= i )`

Comment: for readability and ease of documenting using tools like `doxygen`, please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the while loop is checking for a '\n' as the next character in the input, however the call to : `getline()` will have consumed that char, so the check will never be true.  Also, prompt the user for each input line, so the user knows what they are expected to input.  Otherwise the user will be looking at a blank screen with a blinking cursor and have no indication of what to do next

Comment: suggest re-reading the man page for `getline()` as your understanding is not quite correct.  here is the key details: "If  *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing
       the line, which should be freed by the user program.   (In  this  case,
       the value in *n is ignored.)

       Alternatively, before calling getline(), *lineptr can contain a pointer
       to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size.  If the buffer is not
       large  enough  to  hold the line, getline() resizes it with realloc(3),
       updating *lineptr and *n as necessary."

Comment: this line: `len = getline(&s[k].mostSearch, &len, stdin );` should be: `s[k].mostSearch = NULL; int returnLen = getline( &s[k].mostSearch, &len, stdin );` So 1) getline() mallocs the needed area (which you will need to pass to `free()` when done with it) 2) handling of `len` will not be corrupted by the returned value.

Comment: Note: this function will leak memory like a sieve, because the allocated memory is never passed to `free()` and there is no way to pass a pointer to that allocated memory back to the caller.  Suggest: function declaration be: `s_FRAZE * readFraze( )`  then, instead of `return 0;` use `return s;`  However, there also needs to be some indication in the passed back data when at the end of the filled in structs,  Perhaps by initializing each struct to all NULL, before filling in the fields, so the caller can check the mostSearch ==NULL or freq == 0 as a method of  determining the end

Comment: I compiled the posted code using just `-Wall -pedantic` on ubuntu linux 14.04 using `gcc` and the compiler output a string of warnings and errors.  I compiled the posted code using only `gcc -c -std=c99` and the compiler output a long string of warnings and errors.  Suggest re-checking your method of compiling

Comment: @Levin: `getline` is non-standard. We cannot know every other library. Even more as you do not provide an [mcve].. I still do not see where you `free` any data. This is a good example ... of memory leaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you see a backtrace involving `malloc`, `realloc` or `free`, it means your heap is corrupted: your program overwrote some data structures used by the memory management system. The most common causes for that are writing past the bounds of a block allocated by `malloc` (buffer overflow) and continuing to use a memory block allocated by `malloc` after calling `free` on it (use after free).

As [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) already mentioned in a comment, the size you pass to `malloc` and `realloc` for `s` doesn't match your usage of `s`. `s` is a pointer to an array of `struct fraze`, and you use elements up to `k` of this array, so the memory block must be large enough for `k+1` elements of type `struct fraze`. Given your allocation policy, that means you must leave room for `i` elements of type `struct fraze`. But your actual allocation is for only `sizeof( int )` bytes, which is not enough.

Make that

```
s = malloc(i * sizeof(*s));
```

and (with error checking)

```
s_FRAZE *new_s = realloc(s, i * sizeof(*s));
if (new_s == NULL) {
    fputs("Out of memory!\n", stderr);
    exit(2);
}
s = new_s;
```

Generally speaking, the size of an array of `i` elements that you're assigning the pointer `s` to is `i * sizeof(*s)`. Don't use sizeof(
*TYPE*)