# How do I solve the realloc() invalid next size error with dynamic array in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, scheduling, dynamic-arrays, realloc

I will preface this by stating that I am very new to C and have not had much experience with malloc/realloc etc. I am currently trying to do this assignment simulating disk scheduling (FCFS) for a disk with 800 tracks using an array as the track request queue. Anyways, I am getting this error when I run the program:

*Error in `./a.out': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000650010 Aborted*

I am not surprised as I know that dynamic arrays really shouldn't be a thing, but this is unfortunately what  have to do for my assignment. Any help on fixing this error is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <values.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* function declarations */
int trackReqs();
int numTrack();
void AddToList(int trackNum);
int RemoveFromList();

// global variable declarations/initializations
unsigned seed;
int fileReqs;
bool first = true;
int queue_size = 0;
int* req_queue = NULL; // dynamic array declaration to hold request queue.

void main(){
  printf("Seed for the random number generator: ");
  scanf("%d", &seed);
  srand(seed);
  printf("\n");
  printf("Number of file requests: ");
  scanf("%d", &fileReqs);
  printf("\n");

  req_queue = malloc(sizeof(int)); // allocate memory for the queue array (initially 4 bytes for 1 integer)

  // local variable declarations/initializations
  int totalReqs = 0;
  int numFileReqs = 0;
  float totalHeadMove = 0;
  int currTrack = 0;
  float diff;
  float average;

  do { // do this...
    int numTrackReqs = trackReqs(); // call function to get a random number between 1 and 5 to represent the number of track requests for the current file request
    for (int i = 0; i < numTrackReqs; i++) { // for each track request for the current file request...
      int trackNum = numTrack(); // call function to get a random number between 0 and 799 to represent the number of the track requested
      AddToList(trackNum); // call function to add the track request to the queue
      first = false;
    }
    int nextTrack = RemoveFromList(); // call function to remove the next (first) track request from the queue (signifying that the disk head will be moved to that track) and have that track returned
    diff = abs((float)nextTrack - (float)currTrack); // calculate the head movement for the current file request
    totalHeadMove += diff; // add the head movement for the current file request to the total head movement
    totalReqs++; // increase number of total requests by 1
    currTrack = nextTrack; // make the current track now the next track
    numFileReqs++; // increase number of file requests by 1
  } while(numFileReqs <= fileReqs); // ...for each file request
  average = totalHeadMove / (float) numFileReqs; // calculate the average total head movement for each file request and print the result
  printf("Average head movement: %5.2f", average);
}

int trackReqs(){
  int rand_num = (rand() % (5 - 1 + 1)) + 1; // generate random number from 1 to 5 representing number of track requests for the current file request
  return rand_num;
}

int numTrack(){
  int rand_num = rand() % 800; // generate random number from 0 to 799 representing
  return rand_num;
}

void AddToList(int trackNum){
  if(first != true){ // if it is not the first request being added to the queue...
    realloc(req_queue, sizeof(req_queue) + sizeof(int)); // increase capacity of queue array by 4 bytes (for 1 more integer)
    queue_size++; // increase size of queue by 1
  }
  req_queue[queue_size] = trackNum; // add request to the end of the queue
  return;
}

int RemoveFromList(){
  int first_req = req_queue[0]; // get first request in the queue
  if(queue_size == 0){ // if there is only 0 or 1 request in the queue...
    req_queue[0] = NULL; // make queue empty
  }
  else{
    for(int i = 0; i < queue_size - 1; i++){ // for each request in the queue...
      req_queue[i] = req_queue[i + 1]; // move up 1 position in the queue
    }
    realloc(req_queue, sizeof(req_queue) - sizeof(int)); // decrease capacity of queue array by 4 bytes (for 1 integer)
    queue_size--; // decrease size of queue by 1
  }
  return first_req;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the man:

> void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
>   [...]
>
> The realloc() function **returns** a pointer to the newly allocated memory, which is suitably aligned for any built-in type and may be
>   different from ptr, or NULL if the request fails.

your call is

```
realloc(req_queue, sizeof(req_queue) + sizeof(int))
```

thus you just drop the result of realloc, and as the old pointer may become invalid, you are accessing invalid memory.

On my machine the compiler warned about it:

```
 In function 'AddToList':
test.c:70:5: warning: ignoring return value of 'realloc', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   70 |     realloc(req_queue, sizeof(req_queue) + sizeof(int)); // increase capacity of queue array by 4 bytes (for 1 more integer)
      |
```

^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

BTW, `sizeof(req_queue)`does probably not do what you expect, it returns the size of req_queue, which is a pointer, thus very likely 4 or 8 (depending on your system)

EDIT:
as you asked for more details, here an example of how your add function could look like:

```
void AddToList(int trackNum) {
    int *temp = realloc(req_queue, (queue_size + 1) * sizeof(int));
    if (temp != NULL) 
        req_queue = temp;
    else 
        return; // FIXME would need to handle error correctly here

    queue_size++; // increase size of queue by 1
    req_queue[queue_size - 1] = trackNum; // add request to the end of the queue
    return;
}
```

There are two important points here:
* you need a temporary to get the return value of realloc because if allocation fails, you need to keep the old pointer that remains valid (see [realloc(): invalid next size - realloc dynamic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34254307/realloc-invalid-next-size-realloc-dynamic-struct?rq=1))
* you need to keep track of the **size** you already allocated, thus here `queue_size` is ok but you may notice I use it as a size when you where using it as an index in the array.

You cannot (in standard C) know the size of the hunk of memory you allocated directly from the pointer, you need to keep track of this size yourself. (on BSD, there is non standard malloc_size() AFAIR)

Comment: Okay thank you! Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I still don't understand how I would fix this while also making sure it still does what I intend it to...